# Chrome reloads video on each loop

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I just noticed that Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.99 m) basically reloads a video each time it loops. This occurs with even the most narrowed down version of my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
            <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

This occurs independently of the hosting technique (tried local, Google drive and 2 classic hosting solutions) AND is not related to `cache-control` HTTP headers, those only ensuring the video isn't reloaded from the source each time but from the client-cache.

As it seems to be a Chrome bug and I can make this not too visible for the user I could live with that, but still, on airbnb website, they have a header video looping and NOT being reloaded by Chrome. I tried mimicking their HTML which isn't much more complicated than the example above, video gets reloaded on each loop, so I know for sure there must be some kind of workaround for this implemented on their site. Their JS code is minified though, therefore very hard to debug and I don't have even the beginning of a clue on how they do it. So my question would be: has everybody encountered this issue and found a workaround he could share with us ?

Comment: Were you able to come up with a solution?

Answer (score -2):

This could be caused by having "disabled Cache" ticked in the Chrome Developer Tab.

If not, you can use the App Cache to fix or service worker to load the video from Cache.

This issue was covered here: 
[Why html5 video loop create request each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420929/why-html5-video-loop-create-request-each-iteration)

Probably fixed in newer version of Chrome